# First Wordpress Plugin - Stat Issues

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, statistics

I built my first plugin and after a bumpy start got my plugin downloadable from the WordPress.

On my plugin's stats page it version 1.2.0 is the only active version in the pie chart.

See: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/content-types-wordpress-plugin/stats

Why is that?

Comment: you might get a better response in their support forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I'm having the same problem](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21132/repository-reporting-incorrect-plugin-active-version-stat). Take a look at the opening comments of content-types-wordpress-plugin.php, it looks like there are [extra line breaks between each line](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/content-types-wordpress-plugin/tags/1.6.5/content-types-wordpress-plugin.php), which may disrupt the parser that pulls out the version number, etc. If you don't see the extra breaks when you develop locally, you may have to play with the settings in your text editor; specifically, Unix line breaks vs Mac or Windows ones, but possibly other settings also.

If that doesn't work, compare your comments against [the example in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Standard_Plugin_Information) and [the file header specification](http://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header) to see if you notice any minor differences.

Answer (score 2):

The statistics are way behind the real usage. They may take a week or two to catch up. Just be patient and don’t look to much at the numbers. Real people’s feedback is more important – and more useful.

Comment: It's definitely not the caching. If you take a look at his stats they're still saying the current version is at 100%, even though he's made 9 releases over the past year or so.